# h:selectManyListBox valueChangeListener is not calling

Tags: jsf-2

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1. I am using code in which i am simply using selectManyListBox and i want that when user selects all the values then my valueChangeListener is call. Here what i am doing

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="countryListBox" size="5" value="#{news.saarcCountries}"
                     onselect="form.submit();" valueChangeListener="#{news.changeAppearOnCountryPage}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{news.saarcCountriesMap}"/>
    <f:ajax render="countryPageExpiryCalender" />

</h:selectManyListbox>

<p:calendar id="countryPageExpiryCalender" value="#{news.countryPageExpiryDate}"
            navigator="true" style="z-index: 1;" locale="en" mode="popup"
            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" showOn="button" readOnlyInputText="true"
            disabled="#{!news.appearOnCountryPage}" />
```

I also tried this, instead of onselect i used onchnage like

```
onchange="submit()"
```

Here is my valueChangeListener

```
@ManagedBean(name = "news")
@ViewScoped
public class News {

    private Map<String, String> saarcCountriesMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    private Set<String> saarcCountries = new TreeSet<String>();
    ...

    public void changeAppearOnCountryPage(ValueChangeEvent vcEvent){
        Iterator iter = saarcCountries.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {

            String name = (String)iter.next();
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    } //end of changeAppearOnCountryPage


} //end of class News
```

I want that when user select all the values from the selectmanyListBox, then my valueChangeListener is call, and i check if i have the values in **saarcCountries** variable, then i set **appearOncountryPage = true**, so my calender is render. But my valueChangeListener is not calling. What i am doing wrong?

If i choose onselect, then i want to ask one thing this event will trigger whenever i select the value, of after i have selected all the values. I want that when user select all the values then my ValueChangeListener is call and the values that user selected will be in my saarcCountries variable. So i can check the values that user selected.

I think onchange() is not appropriate in my case. Please help. I am stuck because of it:(

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try it like this:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="countryListBox" size="5" value="#{news.saarcCountries}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{news.saarcCountriesMap}"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{news.changeAppearOnCountryPage}" render="countryPageExpiryCalender"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

You don't need the form.submit(); since you can use the ajax...